# How to give All privilege rights to user ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sudo

I am working with my first VPS.I created a new user

```
    adduser username
```

and then I added this line

```
   username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

under root in

```
   visudo
```

I saved the changes and exit the editor but my new user don't work as root.

(i.e. when i want to restart apache it asks me to login as root)

Is anything else I have to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure you get the distinction. This does not give the privileges, it gives the user the ability to acquire said privileges, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix the command you want to run with `sudo`. At a pinch, `sudo bash`.

I assume you have considered the various reasons why granting a user easy privilege escalation presents a significant security risk, especially on a web facing server?

Comment: First thanks for your time.I don't have any idea about VPS so I read that change PermitRootLogin to no and add a new user with all privilege is most safe is that wrong?Also my problem is that when i want to create a folder or upload a file via filezilla I get permission denied for that new user.

Comment: Denying root login means that people can't - because they know you have a `root` account - then try and hack into it. Hacking root is good, because it gives you full access. 
Running as a nonpriv user with `sudo` access is a security compromise. Your non privileged user is able to work normally, and not risk wrecking the place, and then use sudo if they do actually want to change a system setting. 
That's a two edged sword though - because it still means your nonprivileged user can - effectively - act as root.

Comment: For what it's worth, `sudo su -` gives a root shell which negates the entire "PermitRootLogin" setting. That only prevents direct SSH logins as root ...you've essentially just renamed the root user.

Comment: @Sobrique Ok I think i understand what you mean.So why even if I give to new user all privilege I can not upload or create a folder in filezilla?

Comment: @user3734693 You should be able to upload files and create folders in the home directory of that user. Most other places will need root privileges, so you would have to login as that user using `ssh` and use `sudo` to move files to their final places. But please, if you have more questions, post them as new (but do not forget to search for similar questions first).

Comment: @Sobrique: two points of criticism. Ubuntu has a group `sudo`. It's more sensible to `adduser $USERNAME sudo`. On another note it seems you haven't grasped the meaning of `sudo` and `/etc/sudoers`. It's **not** there to do `sudo su -` it's there to allow a user (or group) mentioned in `sudoers` to impersonate another user on a given host for a given (list of) program(s). That is to say if you are (ab)using `sudo` merely to elevate a user to `root` you should *urgently* read `man sudoers`!